# C# JSON deserialization returns null

Tags: json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some statistics in JSON format from valve's API. The code below doesn't throw any exceptions when deserializing, only when trying to use the statistics afterwards. None of the statistics have a value after deserialization. Valve's response looks like this:

```
"playerstats":{ 
      "steamID":"",
      "gameName":"",
      "stats":[ 
         { 
            "name":"deaths",
            "value":5062
         }, etc etc..
```

This is my Rust class (Rust being the game I'm getting statistics from.):

```
public class Rust
{
    public int steamID { get; set; }
    public string gameName { get; set; }
    public Array stats { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the deserialization code:

```
Rust getStats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rust>(str);

foreach (var stat in getStats.stats) //< ----- Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
{
    parsed += stat.ToString();
}
```

'parsed' is then returned and used to print out all statistics and 'str' is the json response from Valve. I pasted the entire JSON response on pastebin in-case the above data isn't enough: https://pastebin.com/uJZSTF3G

I've tried naming some of the statistics individually in the Rust class instead of using an Array.

I expect the output to show all of the deserialized statistics for example in a console.

Comment: `public Array stats { get; set; }`, i think this can be improved a bit. could you create a class definition for the array's content with two properties, namely `name` and `value`? then replace that `Array` with your `List<YOUR-NEW-CLASS>`. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to do that once I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bagus Tesa suggested, try something like...

```
public class Rust
{
    public int steamID { get; set; }
    public string gameName { get; set; }
    public List<RustStat> stats { get; set; }
}

public class RustStat
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

I changed the steamID property to string and added the full code below.  This compiled for me successfully.  Hope this helps!

```
public class Valve
{
    public Rust playerstats { get; set; }
}

public class Rust
{
    public string steamID { get; set; }
    public string gameName { get; set; }
    public List<RustStat> stats { get; set; }
}

public class RustStat
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

Valve valve = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Valve>(str);

foreach (RustStat stat in valve.playerstats.stats)
{

}
```

Comment: I did that just then and I still get the Object reference exception, any idea why that might be or how to solve it?

Comment: @overflowstack Provided my working code for you.  I changed the "str" var to "json", but this should help!

Comment: @overflowstack I missed another detail and that is the top level "playerstats" element in the JSON payload.  I removed this in my test.  If you need to consume the entire payload as-is, you'll have to include another top level class for this with one Rust property.  Sorry for the confusion.  If you would like I can update my answer.

Comment: If you could update it with the top level class that would be so helpful, I'm fairly new to C# and I'm completely inexperienced with JSON.